# Dynamic array column sizing Pascal Triangle Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to have dynamic array sizing for the columns and below is my approach. However while iterating over a for loop I am getting a constant column size of 1.

```
private int[][] res;

private void populate(int i, int j) {
    if(j == 0 || j == i) {
        res[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
        res[i][j] = res[i-1][j-1] + res[i-1][j];
    }
}

public int[][] generate(int n) {

    res = new int[n][];

    // This part, changing i to n gives me constant columns of size n where empty entries are zeros, keeping col size i returns me constant column of size 1

    for(int i = 1; i <= res.length; i++) {
        res[i-1] = new int[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            populate(i,j);
        }

    }

return res;       
}
```

for n = 3:

Desired output

```
           - [ [1],
               [1,1],
               [1,2,1] ]
```

My output with col size i

```
           -  [ [1] ,
                [1],
                [1] ]
```

My output with col size = 3 = n

```
           -  [ [1,0,0] ,
                [1,1,0],
                [1,2,1] ]
```

How to have dynamic column size for array, without using ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code certainly works for me:

```
Test1 t = new Test1();
int[][] rr = t.generate(5);
for (int[] ints : rr) {
    System.out.println("[ " + Arrays.toString(ints) + "]");
}
```

prints out:

```
[ [1]]
[ [1, 1]]
[ [1, 2, 1]]
[ [1, 3, 3, 1]]
[ [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: Hi. It is giving me an error for java 7 support in an online challenge portal: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/pascal-triangle/ However there java 8 array support works. Think they have a bug in there platform. Thanks for confirming @Piotr